# r code returns positions of given values in a vector

Tags: r, function, vector, position

I am trying to create a function that will return the positive positions of any vector. e.g for simplicity if the vector is `x=c(-2,-1,0,1,2)`, the code should return `4 5`. I am very new to coding, so I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Just `which(x>0)`. The function you are looking for is named `which`

Comment: @nicola ahhh, that's boring.  How about `x[is.finite(sqrt(x)) & x!=0]`  :-)